# go reflection: get correct struct type of interface

Tags: go, reflection

Consider this:

```
type myStruct struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    somelibrary.DoThing(func(thing myStruct) {
        // myStruct should contain unmarshaled JSON
        // provided by somelibrary

        fmt.Printf("%v\n", thing)
    })
}
```

I'm new to Go, so I fear this might not be idiomatic code. I'd like to implement `somelibrary.DoThing` so it correctly infers the struct type from the function argument via reflection, if it's possible. Here's what I have:

```
const jsonData := []byte{`{"foo": "bar"}`}

func DoThing(fn interface{}) {
    // Get first arg of the function
    firstArg := reflect.TypeOf(fn).In(0)
    structPtr := reflect.New(firstArg)

    // Convert to Interface
    // Note that I can't assert this to .(myStruct) type
    instance := structPtr.Elem().Interface()

    // Unmarshal the JSON
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &instance)

    // Call the function
    vfn := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    vfn.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(instance)})
}
```

Without knowing the struct type beforehand, json.Unmarshal just assumes that `instance` is `map[string]interface{}`, so I get a panic when calling `vfn.Call(...)`:

```
panic: reflect: Call using map[string]interface {} as type main.myStruct
```

Is it possible to convert the `instance` interface into the correct type? In other words, can I do type type assertion by passing a string (or using some reflection method) instead of having the type available to the program as a symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here is your code updated:

```
func DoThing(fn interface{}) {
    // Get first arg of the function
    firstArg := reflect.TypeOf(fn).In(0)

    // Get the PtrTo to the first function parameter
    structPtr := reflect.New(firstArg)

    // Convert to Interface
    // Note that I can't assert this to .(myStruct) type
    instance := structPtr.Interface()

    // Unmarshal the JSON
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, instance)

    // Call the function
    vfn := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    vfn.Call([]reflect.Value{structPtr.Elem()})
}
```

Changes made:

1. Pass `structPtr` (a pointer) to `json.Unmarshal`; pass a value and you will not see the changes
2. Remove taking the address of `instance` when passing to `json.Unmarshal`; [there is usually never a good reason to have a pointer to an interface](https://golang.org/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface)
3. Use `structPtr` instead of `instance` when calling `fn`

https://play.golang.org/p/POmOyQBJYC

Comment: note that even though this is correct, OP's code and even intention seem utterly suspicious and wrong and would not pass any sane code review

Comment: @lxe: Remember to [mark this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answered your question.

Comment: @Yerken how so?

Comment: because `DoThing` is nothing more than just unmarshaling into struct, and can be written as simple as: 

```
    json.Unmarshal(somelibrary.JsonData, myStructPtr)
```

Comment: reflect package is a low level package which is relatively slow comparing to other std libs because it does quite a lot of allocations. There are rarely any good reasons to use it and its prone to panics if used without care. For example Tim's code will panic on tons of different cases